# How to run single select statement across all the databases in the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to run a simple select statement across all the databases in the same server. I have around 30-40 databases.  This table has same structure in all the databases.

```
select * from table1 where condition
```

Can you please let me know how to get the records from all databases?? BTW i'm using SQL Server

Comment: Do you mean all *tables* in the same schema?  Or all databases on the same *server*?

Comment: If you really do mean every database on the *server*: cursor over `sys.databases` and then [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for each database. Note: databases have schemas, servers have databases.

Comment: sorry same server.. @Siyual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a cursor for this, `sp_msforeachdB` has a bad reputation for skipping databases.

A solution with a cursor would look something like this.....

```
DECLARE @DB_Name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT Name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb','model','msdb')

OPEN Cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DB_Name

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

   SET @Sql =  N' select * from '+QUOTENAME(@DB_Name)
             + N'.[sechmaName].table1 where condition'

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql
  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DB_Name

END

CLOSE Cur;
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: I just put schema in the question... actually it is the server.. this code is not compiling.. sorry for that.. can you please let me know how to write this one for server..

Comment: @Knowledge2Share Update your question with what have you written.

Comment: cannot see any changes in your question still exactly the same.

Comment: can you please check once.

Comment: No update your question with the query you have written.

Answer (score 2):

```
Exec sp_msforeachdB 'select top 5 cola from dbo.tablea'
```

Comment: **Warning** `sp_msforeachdB` has a bad reputation for skipping databases. use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results in a single result set you can leverage the system views to generate dynamic sql. This also negates the need to use any looping.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select * from ' + db.name + '.table1 where condition union all '
from sys.databases db
--optionally add a where clause here to filter out certain databases
order by db.name

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL 
--uncomment the dynamic sql call when satisfied the sql is correct.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add all of your databases as mentioned in the SQL below:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM Database1.Schema1.Table1
UNION 
SELECT a, b, c FROM Database2.Schema2.Table2
...
```